# Integrating Custom Salesforce Configuration with Zuora Quotes?

Tags: cpq, zuora

We are interested in using Zuora to help pipe our data from Salesforce into our external billing/invoicing system. However, we do not want to integrate Zuora CPQ and we do not have Salesforce CPQ set up either. Instead, we are generating our quotes in SFDC via custom objects. This works great for us - so we'd like to keep our "in-house tool" in place.

To use Zuora's out-of-the-box package, you are required to have either Zuora CPQ or Salesforce CPQ implemented in your Salesforce instance to pipe data out to your billing system. We have neither.

Curious if anyone has set up custom objects in Salesforce to pipe data directly into Zuora? Or, if anyone has direct experience setting up Zuora Quotes in SFDC for a pretty complex use case? Appreciate the help here!

Comment: We've done something very similar for a customer. Zuora has APIs and we've written custom code to integrate our customer's in-house CPQ solution with Zuora. Their Salesforce org was a piece of the overall puzzle.

Comment: so you definitely need to do this with custom code? can't be done via click-to-code automation?

Comment: Take a look at Mulesoft, it has Zuora and SF connectors. A tool like this will allow you to call a Zuora or SF API without writing code but you still need developer-level expertise on how to use Salesforce and Zuora APIs correctly. In our customer base we've seen reluctance with adopting no-code approach for mission-critical integrations such as CPQ. They work well when data is clean, systems are responsive, etc. As soon as something goes wrong and you'll need (for example) retry a failed request, it's rough. Shoot us an email if you want to chat more.